# Styling HTML5 desktop notifications

Tags: css, html, notifications, laravel, desktop

I've included this plugin for desktop notifications in my Laravel 3 project.

> http://aquaron.com/jquery/desktopify

It works fine, only problem is i can't find a way to "style" the notifications!

Is styling the desktop notifications even possible? If it is can someone please point out for me how it is done!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this library uses only `.createNotification()` and not `.createHTMLNotification()`, but Google just dropped .createHTMLNotification() support on version 28. There's [a warning about this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications.html):

*Warning: webKitNotifications.createHTMLNotification() in the web notifications API has been deprecated. The new web notifications API only allows text. Chrome notifications API will be promoted to stable soon and web notifications will be updated to use the new rich notifications format.*

But it is doing it differently, using this [rich notifications](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html).

But this is just for chrome, so if you need it for all browsers, you will have to write your own implementation or find another library to help you.