# Chrome notifications CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, notifications

I use `Chrome` browser notifications in my application and want to build chrome notification preview(how it will looks in browser) before delivering.
Where I may look `css` styles for browser notifications(esp. `font-family` and `font-size`)?

Answer (score 0):

You should refeer to [this](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications) documentation on styling Chrome Notifications.

BTW i don't think you could apply css styles to google chrome web notification system.

Comment: Aaaand here's someone that already asked on stackoverflow
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833814/styling-html5-desktop-notifications

Comment: I just want to use existing notification css and build preview from css components (like screenshot)

Comment: Oh well... u should re-built in css then